# How send mail on Node exit

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

How can I send an email (using `nodemailer` or something else) on node exit?
I know I can't use the event 'onBeforeExit' that is for synchronous tasks only.
I would like to send a notification email on MongoDB lost connection and/or before App crash.
How I can do that?
NPM module `async-exit-hook` seems promising but I was not able to figure it out how sen emails.
Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Haven't tried something like that, but try this, make an independent module for sending mail which accepts cli arguments( node mail.js --to X --from Y --subject T --body U) and spawn a *detached* process of it when SIGHUP triggers, You could try using setTimeout for delays if the script exits before execution, just my two cents

Answer (score 0):

You can listen on **uncaughtException** and trigger email from there, and for mongo connection, in your catch or error section of mongo connection code trigger the email.

check this for more

https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception

*create a single method to trigger email, and invoke it in both the places.*